# Which VLQ flags require moderator intervention?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flagging, answers

[This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/457687) to [Exporting geodata from QGIS to File Geodatabase](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/102189/115) is another declined review instance that gives me the impression that I am bothering the moderators. Regardless of the content, the decline reason is:

> Declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of
> content that requires their intervention

So, it seems that I shouldn't have flagged it as VLQ because it will make moderators aware. But isn't there a review queue specifically for determining whether a post is very low quality?

By the logic of the decline reason, should we stop flagging for VLQ because it will make a moderator aware?

More technically, which VLQ flags require moderator attention?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the moderator who declined your flag.

The poster has attempted to answer a question and has just done so poorly. I think this is a low quality post and should be addressed using a comment, edit and/or downvote without need for moderator intervention.

Please do not flag such posts. Simply comment, edit and/or downvote them instead.

For advice on when to use Very Low Quality flags, which is rarely, I recommend [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/215590) to [Is the Very Low Quality flag too ambiguous?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595)

I am not an expert in all ways that flags can reach the moderators, but once they do, the moderators must decide what to do with them.  They can only mark them as Helpful or Decline them. There is no Skip option like the Review Queues offer regular users.

Comment: Though this is an answer, it does not answer the question: Which VLQ flags require moderator intervention. By your own admission: `The poster has attempted to answer a question and has just done so poorly. ` So this is not an `Not an answer` issue, and a low quality issue. The question I asked is why a moderator had to step in and decline it; not whether if the quality is low enough (as that's subjective).

Comment: @tinlyx if that’s your question then please ask just that in your question but I cannot speak to why another moderator processed your flag the way they did. My answer is that I would have declined it too, and I explained why.

Comment: Just for the record, I asked just that in the title.

Comment: @tinlyx posed one question in the title (which is intended to summarize the body) and three related questions in the body. I think asking single focused questions is the best way to get focused answers, even on Meta sites.

Answer (score 0):

What were you expecting the moderator (me in this case) to do. The answer is correct so while it isn't great I don't think it should be deleted, could you not just downvote it?

To be honest I'm not entirely sure what the point of vlq flags are.

Comment: `What were you expecting the moderator (me in this case) to do.` Maybe nothing? That's the assumption I had, i.e. the community can decide, and the moderators do not need to be bothered unless they see a reason to override.